# space between 2 column names with php from sql

Tags: php, sql, concatenation

I ve got the idea of basic Concat with sql but i cant get a space between first and surname on my drop down menu. The code all works its just a basic thing i cant find to give me a space between the first name and the last name.

```
  <option value=""  >Valuer of this Property</option>

  <?php 
  $res=mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT CONCAT(first,surname) from listalot_users");
  while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($res))
  {
    ?>
      <option><?php echo $row['CONCAT(first,surname)']; ?></option>

  <?php
}

?>
    </select>
```

Comment: `CONCAT( first, ', ', surname )`.

Comment: Also add a name to a new concat-ed field to make it simplier to use, as shown in my answer

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_concat-ws `SELECT CONCAT_WS(' ', first, surname)...`

Comment: didn't work....

Comment: Which didn't work? What did occur?

Comment: Dai 's , i ve not checked your link yet, but thanks in advance,,just looked at manual thanks but they don't seem to ever help me. same as php manual,,

Comment: It's pretty much the same as @iXCray unless you wanted to separate multiple (+2) columns.

Comment: So i f i add 
CONCAT( first, ', ', surname )  into the query it would work?  i got an error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  <option value=""  >Valuer of this Property</option>

  <?php 
  $res=mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT CONCAT(first,' ',surname) as full_name from listalot_users");
  while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($res))
  {
    ?>
      <option><?php echo $row['full_name']; ?></option>

  <?php
}

?>
    </select>
```

Comment: worked!!!!  nice one. would never have thought you get the space from the query and not just add a space on the echo....crazy world

Comment: @Glen You could get the names separately in the query, and then add the space in PHP.

Comment: How?  that would make more sense.

Comment: echo $row['name']." ".$row['surname'];

Answer (score 0):

Update you code like this:

```
<option value=""  >Valuer of this Property</option>

  <?php 
  $res=mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT CONCAT(first, ' ', surname) as fullname from listalot_users");
  while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($res))
  {
    ?>
      <option><?php echo $row['fullname']; ?></option>

  <?php
}

?>
    </select>
```

Comment: He never said anything about adding a comma, he just wants a space.